# How can I calculate coordinates of the perpendicular line?

Tags: geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

Lines (x1, y1), (x2, y2) and (x3, y3), (x4, y4) are perpendicular. I have coordinates of points (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) and length in pixels of a line (x3, y3), (x4, y4). I need to find coordinates of point (x4, y4). What is the pseudocode for calculating (x4, y4)?

[image: picture]

Comment: You shouldn't draw P3 on the line segment P1P2, this is misleading.

Comment: @Yves Daoust. But (x3,y3) is located on the line (x1, y1), (x2, y2). How I can draw it other way?

Comment: If P3 is guaranteed to be on P1P2, then one of P1 or P2 is extraneous.

Comment: @Yves Daoust There is line from P1 to P2. On that line there is P3. So P1,P2,P3 are the points that are located on line P1P2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calculate vector A where

```
 A = (x2 - x1,y2 - y1)
```

A vector perpendicular to this is given by

```
 B = (y1 - y2, x2 - x1)
```

find the normalised vector

```
 C = B/|B|
```

where `|B|` is simply the modulus of vector `B` calculated using pythagoras

Your point `(x4,y4)` will then be given as

```
 (x4,y4) = (x3,y3) + K*C
```

where K is the length of the line `(x3,y3)` to `(x4,y4)` (which you say in the question that you know). Depending on the orientation of your points, you may need to set the value of K to

```
 K = -K
```

in order for the point to be correct to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for a help. I think I did it the way you said but it did not worked. The line(x1, y1), (x2, y2) is not perpendicular to line (x3, y3), (x4, y4). What is wrong here? http://pastebin.com/ZSwy4e2J

Comment: @vasili111 you have a mistake. it should be b = x2-x1  
a = y1 - y2   . You should see it work now.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you again. Also, if someone wants to implement that algorithm should keep in mind that, if points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) have some values, the result will be "undefined" or something like that depending on the implementation of programming language used. That is because you cant divide number by 0.